# Python: List of integers to datetime?

Tags: python

I have a list `[14,9,11,2,1,21]` and I want to transform it in datetime object (e.g. `2014/09/11 02:01:21`)

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> x = [14,9,11,2,1,21]
>>> datetime(x)
TypeError: an integer is required
```

v Something like this works, but it's obviously not the right way to go around it:

```
>>> datetime(x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5], x[6])
```

How should I do this?

Comment: What parts of the datetime are the different integers supposed to represent?

Comment: _obviously not the right way to go_.  Why is that?  Only you know how to map between the two representations.

Comment: @SimonBrahan Sorry, I updated the question

Comment: @jonrsharpe Nice, you're right

Comment: @jonrsharpe now it looks like I nicked your comment to make an answer... sorry.... didn't even see your comment while I was writing an answer :(

Comment: @JonClements not a problem, it's hardly a secret technique! Have a +1 for remembering to add the year.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not ideal, but you can unpack after adding 2000 to the "year" (otherwise you end up with year 14), e.g.:

```
from datetime import datetime

x = [14,9,11,2,1,21]
x[0] += 2000
dt = datetime(*x)
# 2014-09-11 02:01:21
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to expand the arguments contained in your list `x`:

```
x = [14,9,11,2,1,21]
dt = datetime(x[0]+2000, *x[1:])  # The star expands the remaining integers into arguments for datetime()
# 2014-09-11 02:01:21
```

This solution has the advantage of being more direct than Jon's and of not modifying the input list (which makes it more generally useful).

PS: If you needed to modify a value in the middle (say the 3rd value), then this would be more complicated, and Jon's answer might be more legible in this case:

```
other_function(*(x[:2] + [x[2]+2000] + x[3:]))  # A new list is first created with the modified arguments
```

Comment: +1 from me for a well explained alternative to my answer (explaining the diff between mutating the list and creating slices and such). If I did care about the original list, then I'd go for your first suggestion as a first choice.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Eric Lebigots [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25844882/5108699), you could use enumerate inside a list comprehension to target multiple indices. This also doesn't modify the input list.

For example, if you wanted to add 2000 to the year and also add 12 hours for some reason:

`datetime(*[n+2000 if y == 0 else n+12 if y == 3 else n for y,n in enumerate([14,9,11,2,1,21])])`